# How to resolve 'Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x96\xA4 t...' for column 'campaign_name' at row 1' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

**I have changed charset and collation utf8 to utf8mb4 but still getting error. I am using the 5.7 version of MySQL.**

I am getting error in this String.

String str = "Instagram Post:  ";

**I have executed these statements to changed charset and collation utf8 to utf8mb4.**

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4; 
ALTER DATABASE the_dimaag_prod CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
SET character_set_server = 'utf8mb4';
```

To show the changed I executed this statement.

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

**Also changed table and column charset and collation utf8 to utf8mb4.**

You can see in images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to set charset in your database connection as well `utf8mb4`

Comment: How can I set database connection  as well utf8mb4 ?

Comment: share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and the query that caused this error

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbcampaign` (
   `campaign_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `account_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `campaign_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `campaign_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `start_date` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`campaign_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Comment: And getting error while inserting string with emoji in this table.  this is data source url 'spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/the_dimaag_prod?rewriteBatchedStatements=true'

Comment: I am getting error in this String. 

String str = "Instagram Post:  ";